# MySQL Import running out of memory with "mysql" command

Tags: mysql

I'm running `mysql -u root -p 'databasename' < /path/to/file.sql` and am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tr' at line 90
mysql> Aborted
```

I'm trying to find out how to work around this temporarily... one of the things I've tried is adding `--max_allowed_packet=512M` to the command.

The .sql file is 120MB.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL file is broken. It was probably generated by a PHP script that bailed out. The error you see is a PHP error, not a MySQL error.

Check your SQL file at line 90.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL client is not running out of memory. There is a PHP error message in your SQL file. MySQL doesn't understand PHP error messages, so it complains about a syntax error.

The PHP error message in your SQL file is at line 90 and looks like:

> `<br />`
>   `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tr`

The MySQL client is trying to be helpful and displays the part of the file it doesn't understand. This is probably why you thought the MySQL client was running out of memory.

Correct your SQL file and the error should disappear.